# Why isn't data being written to my Amazon DynamoDB table?

Tags: node.js, amazon-dynamodb, alexa-skills-kit

I'm currently creating an amazon alexa skill that lets users create lists and recall them later with help from AWS's DynamoDB. When my skill attempts to `put` items into the database table, things turn up green and no errors happen. However, when checking the database table, nothing is written there. Here is the code from my skill where I try to take a slot value and put it into the database:

```
// query DynamoDB to see if the item exists first
docClient.get(checkIfItemExistsParams).promise().then(data => {
    console.log('Get item succeeded', data);

    const groceryItem = data.Item;

    if (groceryItem) {
      const errorMsg = `Grocery item ${name} already exists!`;
      this.emit(':tell', errorMsg);
      throw new Error(errorMsg);
    }
    else {
      // no match, add the recipe
      return docClient.put(dynamoParams);
    }
  })
  .then(data => {
    console.log('Add item succeeded', data);

    this.emit(':tell', `Grocery item ${name} added!`);
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.error(err);
  });
```

And here are the server logs first for my skill preparing the request, then for the request actually being sent. No errors occur before or after:

```
2018-05-21T02:19:53.937Z    72ba8ffb-5c9d-11e8-83b7-af0480d5c4a1    Attempting to add item to list { TableName: 'Groceries',
Item: 
{ Name: 'apples',
UserId: 'userid was here, not sure if I should show that publically' } }


host: 'dynamodb.us-east-1.amazonaws.com',
port: 443,
hostname: 'dynamodb.us-east-1.amazonaws.com',
pathname: '/',
path: '/',
href: 'https://dynamodb.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/' },
_clientId: 1 },
operation: 'putItem',
params: 
{ TableName: 'Groceries',
Item: 
{ Name: 'apples',
UserId: 'userid was here, not sure if I should show that publically' } },
```

Anyone have any ideas on what might be happening? Thanks.

Comment: Where did the `"Attempting to add item to list"` log come from? Can you post that code too? Also, what is the output from the `console.log('Add item succeeded', data);` line?

Comment: I suspect you'll find that `docClient.put()` without a callback returns an unstarted `AWS.Request`... not a response.

Comment: I think I found the solution. I was initially trying to use es6 promises to handle the dbget, dbput, dbscan etc. callbacks before I learned that the dynamo client comes pre-packaged with its own promises. So simply adding `.promise()` after my `docClient.put|get|scan|delete()` calls seemed to work, but I'll have to test it fully

Comment: Have a look at the Alexa Skill Kit SDK v2 and the DynamoDB persistence adapter: https://github.com/alexa/alexa-skills-kit-sdk-for-nodejs